# error when saving the str(getting from response.content) as an image

Tags: python, image, request, base64

i am using the requests in python to hit an api and get a response:

```
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

i have image data in response.content

```
    print type(response.content)
```

gives:

```
<type 'str'>
```

now i have to save this data as an image file on my local :
i am using ubuntu 16.04 and python 2.7

i am trying this:

```
    image=response.content
    result=open('img.png','wb')
    result.write(image)
```

but when trying to open the resulting file, this error is shown:

```
Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file
```

`response.content` looks like this (shortened sample):

```
eyJpZCI6IndzX2Y5YnVqaWVwamVzMnRyNWpjM2RpXzE1MTY2MTM5MjgzMzMi‌​LC.............YTZPZ‌​UVjWkwva0FBQUFBRWxGV‌​GtTdVFtQ0MifQ==
```

i have also tried encoding response.content to base64 encoding and then tried writing my image without success.
what should i do?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: the image is getting saved when opened it says:

Comment: Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file

Comment: What does `response.content` look like?

Comment: it looks like this:

Comment: its too lon to fit here:

Comment: eyJpZCI6IndzX2Y5YnVqaWVwamVzMnRyNWpjM2RpXzE1MTY2MTM5MjgzMzMiLC.............YTZPZUVjWkwva0FBQUFBRWxGVGtTdVFtQ0MifQ==

Comment: Please edit your question instead of hiding additional, unformatted information in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this :

```
image=response.content
fh = open("imageToSave.png", "wb")
fh.write(base64.decodebytes(image))
fh.close()
```

Comment: same error : it generates a png image named imageToSave.png but when opened it says: Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file

Comment: Then I think the problem with the response.content. Just check whether it returns exact image string or not .

Comment: yes actually the problem was there: the image data from response.content is producing error where as , if i do response.json()['image']  this produces the image.

Comment: So the issue is fixed ?